# Repository for humorous items posted on the main site.

Tags: discussion, meta, humor

Seeing this phrase in a mathematics question

> what is it good for ... and does it relate to 3D graphics?

made me curious if there is general interest in a meta thread or chat room to archive some of the intentional and accidental humor that comes through the main site.  There has been some priceless material over the years but it gets lost or deleted quickly.

Comment: The particular example is unclear to me. I see neither intentional nor accidental humor (but I am also very tired, so I might just overlook it).

Comment: I was imagining "what it is good for; and does it relate to 3D graphics" as the all-purpose response for every social situation.

Comment: Not sure how to best use the available resources (meta or chat?), but I'd be in favor of this. We do need more levity. The point raised by quid does stand. Let's keep it good-natured.

Comment: Already exists, in a way: [Gems from Stack Exchange](http://gemsfromstackexchange.tumblr.com/)

Comment: @NormalHuman Indeed, the *idea* exists. I'm sad to see that's mostly a showcase of trolls.

Comment: Related: [Where is the proper place for math jokes?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/12762/where-is-the-proper-place-for-math-jokes)

Comment: This week brought a sublimely titled Question, "poof by induction".

Answer (score 9):

This would be a quite non-constructive activity, and I am afraid quite frequently somebody would feel insulted. I am against it.

Comment: It's also constructive, or at least beneficial in some way.  The humor items can be posted without links to particular questions.

Comment: Well, I sure could see myself giggling over one or  another entry. Link or not, chances are OPs will recognize what they wrote.

Comment: I think we both understood each other, but to be clear: I have in mind something like a chat thread where only the funny text is quoted, with no other information about the poster or posting.   Of course some people will look up the originals.

Comment: Some will not have to look up the originals because they *wrote* them or saw them otherwise.

Comment: As I said, we did understand each other.   I disagree as to the importance, frequency or severity of the event that occasional non-amused OPs will see their work quoted in a humor list.